# Changing from H-4 to F-1 visa. Will my EAD filing remain valid?

Tags: usa, immigration, h4-visa

I will be changing from H-4 to F-1 visa in July-2019 (Visa appointment scheduled). But we applied for H-4 EAD around a month ago. Will my EAD filing remain valid? Do I need to withdraw the EAD filing? Will it create any problems when I apply for F-1 OPT eventually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An H-4 EAD would only be valid while you are in H-4 status. So even if you get the EAD, you could only use it to work if you were in H-4 status (e.g. if you entered the US on an H-4 visa).